# log4j2 configuration file not found

Tags: java, logging, ant, log4j2

I'm struggling to understand what is wrong with this issue.

I have a java project (no Eclipse/Maven) structured like the following:

```
├── build
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── oata
│   │       └── HelloWorld.class
│   └── jar
│       └── HelloWorld.jar
├── build.xml
├── lib
│   ├── log4j-api-2.3.jar
│   └── log4j-core-2.3.jar
├── myManifest
└── src
    ├── log4j2.xml
    └── oata
        └── HelloWorld.java
```

when building with ant I keep getting that the log4j2 config file cannot found.
I already looked at similar questions and the common issues were regarding that the xml file was not in the classpath, which is not my case. Anyway this is the error:

```
[java] ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

This is my config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration package="oata"
status="WARN">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="oata.HelloWorld" level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming you are executing java class using Ant build script.

`No log4j2 configuration file found` means `log4j2.xml` configuration file is not in your classpath.

Please verify HelloWorld.jar includes log4j confuguration file or not.

Alternate way set log4j confuguration file path as system property in your build script.

```
<sysproperty key="log4j.configurationFile" value="file:///${basedir}/src/log4j2.xml" />
```

Here is a documentation for [log4j configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer! I hadn't the .xml in the jar, so adding the sysproperty worked.

Comment: Welcome @geek4079 :)

Comment: PERFECT ! Thanks. it also works for me with value="src/log4j2.xml"

Comment: @Jack' Where did you put the code snippet?